# Google wallet integration in android

Tags: android-pay

In the poc given by Google, it is not mentioned about the payment process. Where will the stipulated amount be transferred? There is no way to add the seller's details.

Will google wallet save only our card details and we must use getFullWallet() and use the details to continue process by  using another third party payment gateway?or it will handle all the transactions? if so, where can we give seller details in the code?

Any POC on complete google wallet usage will be very much helpful as I couldn't understand the flow in the sample provided.

As in the sample the currency is converted to dollars, is that the case always?

What if I have a card and it is not internationally valid?

A piece of simple code is appreciated.

After getting fullwallet how can we use that to send details to merchant's account?

Will Google Wallet act as payment gateway?

Comment: [This FAQ](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/faq) may help with conceptual questions. Hth...

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I found out that Google-Wallet as its name suggests acts as our personal digital wallet and will not be involved in any of the payment gateway process. After fetching the details from Google-Wallet i.e..,getFullWallet() we can send these details to our server which implements the payment gateway on its side.